Can STM32 PWM settings affect other timer settings?
#include "Main.h"

#define MAX_Intensity 1600

static volatile uint16_t Intensity = 10;

void Timer4_Configuration(void)
{
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_BaseStructure;

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);

    TIM_BaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 1 - 1;
    TIM_BaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_BaseStructure.TIM_Period = MAX_Intensity - 1;
    TIM_BaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TIM_BaseStructure);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}

void PWM_Configuration()
{
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCStructure;
    TIM_OCStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIM_OCStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;

    TIM_OC1Init(TIM4, &TIM_OCStructure);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_OC2Init(TIM4, &TIM_OCStructure);
    TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    TIM_OC3Init(TIM4, &TIM_OCStructure);
    TIM_OC3PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    TIM_OC4Init(TIM4, &TIM_OCStructure);
    TIM_OC4PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
}

void GPIO_PWM_Configuration()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin   = ALL_LEDS;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);
}

void TIM2_Configuration(u32 Intervalms)
{
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;

    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler   = 16000-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period      = Intervalms-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);

    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1);
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;

    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
    {
        if(Intensity > MAX_Intensity)
        {
            Intensity = 10;
        }
        TIM4->CCR1 = Intensity;
        TIM4->CCR2 = Intensity;
        TIM4->CCR3 = Intensity;
        TIM4->CCR4 = Intensity;

        Intensity = Intensity * 2;
        
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    GPIO_PWM_Configuration();
            
    Timer4_Configuration();
    
        // Do not work
    PWM_Configuration();
    TIM2_Configuration(500);
    
        // Do work
    //TIM2_Configuration(500);
        //PWM_Configuration();
    
    while(1)
    {
    }
}



The code above is the example I am referring to. However, the Timer2 interrupt does not occur in this code. However, if you change the TIM2_Configuration function call to before the PWM_Configuration function call, the interrupt operates normally. I can't find the cause of this behavior, so I'm asking a question.
i'm conducting practice using STM32F407G-DISC1.
STM32F407G-DISC1
I called the printf function for debugging, but an interrupt occurred in any order.

TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_BaseStructure; if you use local structures you need zero them before use as other fields may contain garbage values TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_BaseStructure = {};  Other structures as well.

Yuo need to clear the flag at the beginning of the interrupt handler as it has to propagate through the bus. If it does not - you will enter the interrupt again and again ....

The basic answer is no, one timer cannot mess with another.  There is a chaining feature where one timer can send a signal to another to start or stop it etc, but the recipient has to be specifically configured to act on that.
So you have some other problem.

@0___________ I would say that's probably the bug, or at least it is a bug - you could post that as the answer.
